# Finding radius of a circle inside of a circle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have $n$ small circles inside of a circle. The radius of big circle is given to be $R$. I need to find the radius of the small circle. I have a solution, but I don't understand it. I need explanation of that solution.

[image]

Comment: Actually I need an explanation of this solution!

Comment: You need to describe the problem first.

Comment: Hint: In the triangle in the diagram, try dropping a perpendicular from the opposite vertex onto the side of length $2r$ and examine the sides and angles of one of the sub-triangles.

Comment: @YeasinRahaman You can edit your question to state that you need an explanation of the given solution!

Comment: There is a large circle with radius R and n little circles each having radius r, are placed inside on the border of the large circle.There should be no space between the circles. R and n is given. I have to calculate r .

Comment: To be more precise, you seem to be looking at small disks around the inside edge of a large disk.  Otherwise it gets more complicated, for example as at [Erich's Packing Centre](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirincir/) or [Eckard Specht's site](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/cci.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are n circles, angle $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{n}$(Complete angle should be $2\pi$).

Let's now look at red triangle. Since it's isosceles, its median and angle bisector is the same line. So the bottom side (of new triangle) is equal to $r$, and according to sines law you have 
$\frac{\sin \theta}{r}=\frac{1}{R-r}$ Then after some algebra you'll get 
$r=\frac{R\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{1+\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}$ Which is your answer.

[Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)

[Isosceles triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle)

Second eq. on the picture is just solution for R(r).